# How to save R source code to a PDF

Tags: r

So I have some R source code, how do I save that source code into a PDF. I am able to save the markdown output as PDF through knitr. But how do I save the code itself onto a PDF?

Comment: why not do this out of R?

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo = TRUE` in your R chunk